# Total number of squares possible on $n\times n$ square dots

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

For total  number of squares possible on $n\times n$ square dots, I know the formula is

$$\frac{n^2(n^2-1)}{12}
$$

But this is only works for the squares formed by lines which join the the $n\times n$ dots. For example

[image]

Here the squares formed by the intersection of lines are not considered. Here the squares $L_1g_5e_4h_5$ , $g_5J_1j_5e_4$, $e_4j_5B_1i_5$,   $h_5e_4i_5N_1$ are not counted.

If we connect all lines it will look something like this.

[image]

More squares will emerge here.

I looked for total possible numbers of lines and dots here
[1](http://www.survo.fi/papers/PointsInGrid.pdf)
[2](http://www.survo.fi/papers/LinesInGrid2.pdf).

But I could not proceed any further.

I was wondering if there is some general formula for finding all possible number of squares if we consider all the squares which are formed by intersection of lines on $n\times n$ dots i.e all possible number of squares formed by all the points. I am also hoping for something similar for total number of triangles.

**Edit:**
To be more precise I want all these squares to be counted in $3 \times 3 $ dots grid, [image]

But the aforesaid formula only considers these squares,

[image]

For $4 \times 4$ dots grids,

[image]

I made this manually, so I might have missed some squares.

Comment: Total number of triangles is easy if there's no constraint as such, we just need to chose 3 points from the the $n \times n$ board. I think it will be hard to speak for squares made from intersection of lines...

Comment: @SwagBeastSKJJ _Everything_ is easy if we only use the points from the the $n\times n$ board, disregarding the intersections. This is not the case, though.

Comment: @AmpNotion To help clear things up a bit, how many squares do you count in the diagram you provided? If you could work out the first few values of the sequence, OEIS might help, otherwise can you post them here so everyone can be sure they're solving the same problem?

Comment: Sorry, one more point for clarification: do you want to look at the number of squares defined by the intersections of the *segments* joining pairs of lattice points, or the full *lines* joining them? This makes a difference for $n>3$.

Comment: @ChrisLewis I edited the post and added which squares I want to be considered.

Comment: How did you encounter this problem?

Comment: I'm getting for $n=3,4,5$ the square counts $21, 1008, 10000$.  Here's an example square in the $n=3$ case (I think is missing in the animation): https://ibb.co/ys0qxC5

Comment: For $n=6$ the number I got is $139253$.